# About C++ invalid references, is creating or using that makes a program ill-formed?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

See this little piece of code:

```
std::deque<BIG> bigs {};
// add some BIGs in the deque

BIG& last_BIG { bigs.front() };
f(last_BIG);
bigs.pop_front();
g();
```

After the `pop_front` call the reference `last_BIG` is invalid, is this enough to make the program ill-formed? In other words do I have to put `last_BIG` in a smaller scope?

Of course *using* `last_BIG` after the popping is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, having an invalid reference or an invalid pointer by itself does not invalidate your program. Using it after it became invalid would definitely be undefined, but creating it is not by itself a problem.

This is similar to creating hanging pointers, except that pointers offer more ways to invalidate them:

```
int *a = new int;
delete a;
```

At this point `a` is an invalid pointer, in the same way that after `pop_front` in your code `last_BIG` is an invalid reference. This OK, as long as you do not dereference an invalidated pointer or access an invalidated reference.

Comment: I have no doubts about pointers, but all this "you cannot have null references, unless in very sick programs" confused me. So it is the same concept.

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni: The "no null references" is because you'd have to dereference (i.e. use) a null pointer to get one. And after that dereference, you enter Undefined Behavior territory and cannot sensibly talk about C++ anymore.

Comment: @MSalters, makes sense. I guess my confusion comes from the fact I was not considering "Null reference" literally, but more as an invalid one.

Answer (score 0):

In essence when you use & you are taking the memory address of an of the BIG object. If the memory address is in the Heap (made with new) then you are fine. On the other hand, if its a reference on the stack, then this will be technically invalid once you leave the function you are currently in. Regardless, the object had to be declared, and memory had to be allocated for it.

So no, this does not make last_BIG be invalid.